# How long could the ISS function if removed from Earth orbit?

Tags: iss, life-support

Suppose the ISS were instantaneously moved to the opposite side of the Sun from Earth - how long would it continue to function? Are there any systems aboard that depend on passing behind the planet regularly, or communications from Mission Control? What would be the first system to fail?

Comment: I'm under the impression that astronauts do an awful lot of maintenance. And stationkeeping would probably become an issue.

Comment: Thermal control will be trickier.  100% sunlight now only lasts a few days at a time.  It will be constant away from earth.  Some rotation might mitigate that, though.

Comment: Also there is a lot of software changes that would have to happen. I am unsure how the ISS dues attitude control currently (is there an earth sensor?) and whether the solar arrays track the brightest point in the sky or are set to fixed angles for each time.

Comment: Mission Control sends hundreds if not thousands of commands to the ISS every day.

Comment: Eating would be a problem within a couple of months. That's what *I'd* be worried about.

Comment: Is the station crewed or uncrewed at the time of teleport? if crewed, how many people?

Comment: I'm assuming a "normal" state for the station, so three to six crew.

Comment: I wonder how much protection the ISS receives from Earth's magnetic field and how long its systems and crew would survive without it.

Comment: @Schwern long term they would all develop a higher cancer risk but they would be long dead before any radiation associated medical problems arise (unless they are hit by freak solar activity or similar stellar phenomena).

Comment: @Dragongeek I also wonder about the electronics and solar panels.